# In Rust, Does Modifying a Borrowed Pointer Change the Original Value?

Tags: pointers, vector, rust

This is Rust 0.4

I believe it does, but it doesn't seem to be true for my particular use case.

I have an owned pointer to a vector of owned pointer to vector's.

I construct it as the following.

```
let mut table = ~[];
for [0, ..10].each |i| {
    let mut row = ~[];
    for [0, ..128].each |j| {
        row.push(A_CERTAIN_ENUM);
    }
    table.push(row);
}
```

Then, I pass this two dimensional vector to another function for further initialization.

The function looks something like this.

```
fn setT (table: &mut ~[~[SomeEnumType]]) {
    // Demonstration purposes...
    for [0, ..10].each |i| {
        for [0, ..128].each |j| {
            table[*i][*j] = A_DIFFERENT_ENUM;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the function with the following code.

```
setT(&table);
```

However, then upon inspection, the content of `table` is **not** changed at all!
Everything inside is still `A_CERTAIN_ENUM` rather than `A_DIFFERENT_ENUM`.

Does anyone know how to have another function modify the parameter you pass to it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Rust are you using? Didn't the type checker complain about using

```
setT(&mut table);
```

I am a little stumped too. Of course, pointers should work as expected!

Comment: I'm using 0.4.. So you are saying I cant do things like `setT(&mut table)`?

Comment: I believe that Bilal is pointing out a discrepancy in your initial write-up.  You wrote "setT(&table)", which should have produced a type-error because it would result in an *immutable* borrowed pointer rather than a mutable one.    I too would have expected a type error at this point (and if you don't get one, it sounds like a bug).

Comment: I'll double check if that's the case once I get home. Though I'm quite sure I did write `setT(&table)`... which would perhaps explain why the value wasn't modified? The compiler mistakenly decided to pass a copy or something.. not even sure if that's possible lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of a similar code (rustc 0.5, commit 19f5f91):

```
enum Direction {
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West
}

fn main() {
    let mut table = ~[];
    for [0, ..10].each |i| {
        let mut row = ~[];
        for [0, ..128].each |j| {
            row.push(North);
        }
        table.push(copy row);
    }
    io::print(fmt!("before: %d\n", table[0][0] as int));
    setT(&mut table);
    io::print(fmt!("after: %d\n", table[0][0] as int));
}

fn setT(table: &mut ~[~[Direction]]) {
    for [0, ..10].each |i| {
        for [0, ..128].each |j| {
            table[*i][*j] = East;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
before: 0
after: 1
```

Comment: I'm using Rust 0.4, but is 0.5 out? I saw the 0.5 milestone thingy on github still has like 19 days to go. I don't have rust set up on my work machine, so I wont be able to investigate more until I get home... :-(

Comment: 0.5 is not yet released.  That just means "whatever is most recent in Git".